# SQL to Group Data based on ParentID and Child ID

Tags: sql, netsuite, suitescript

[image]

Hi Everyone,

I am new to SQL.
I have the following table as above

Columns shown in the images are **"Name"** **"ID"** **"Parent"**.

**Expected Output:**

I need to view it in hierarchy model

Eg. If the "ID" is 1, I need to fetch all the "Parent" is 1 and show it below the row of "ID" is 1.

Note: I should show parents twice.
Example:

The above image has an "ID" 3 and "Parent" 3 Twice.
All parents should repeat Twice

The result should be as.

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please tag the question with the RDBMS you're using (SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...)

Comment: Please specify what kind of solution you are looking for, if ```SQL``` query then will ID be in your ```where``` clause?